# How to configure paths in Firebase cloud storage

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, path, firebase-storage

This is a very general question, so im using Firebase cloud storage with unity, and to store a file I must give it a full path to the reference location.

such as

```
Firebase.Storage.StorageReference _ref = storageRef.Child("images/rivers.jpg");
```

Now my problem is what is the best way to structure paths for files, as seen above the path is "images/rivers.jpg, it's hardcoded and it's taken directly from Firebase examples, but should i make an ID for each file and store them by their IDs (and if so, how ?) or since i already have access to the files physical paths from user's devices should i make the path with that? what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a design problem, which answer depends on your specific situation.

One example could be if you're storing images for players avatars.

You'd read the file from the local storage regardless of its name on the user computer, you only need the image data, then save that data as

```
string id = player.ID;
string imagePath = $"images/{id}.jpg";
var avatarReference = Firebase.Storage.DefaultInstance.GetReference(imagePath);
```

This way the image is always retrievable by the player's id which never changes.

Comment: Excellent, but what about the use case of a user having many images, plus other users can query for these images?